# Syntax error in php explode code

Tags: php

I had some code added that deals with canonical links but it doesn't seem to be working. One line of code that is repeated in several files shows a red mark next to it in Dreamweaver so i suspect this is wrong.

```
$pid = explode('=',explode('&',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])[0]);
```

Can anyone see an obvious reason this would be flagged up by DW. I don't see any unclosed brackets or ' in it so i'm a bit lost.

Update:
It appears there is a fundamental error in the original code as the var $pid[1] is never given the correct data.

I tried using the split code answer below and if i print_r this

```
$qs = explode('&',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

the result is Array ( [0] => main_page=index [1] => cPath=70_229_242_240 )

Then print_r the second part

```
$pid = explode('=',$qs[0]);
```

gives a result of index

This is incorrect.

A simplified version of the code using the results is

```
if($pid[1] == '70_229_242_240'){
echo " true";
}
```

So you can see that what I actually need to have stored in $pid is taken from cPath=70_229_242_240

I've tried to change the explode to give me this data but i can't get the correct result. TBH, they always confuse the hell out of me.

RESOLVED.

Used $pid = explode('=',$qs[1]);

Comment: The function array dereferencing syntax `function()[]` is only available in PHP 5.4+. What's your version?  this is a common cause of `unexpected [` errors.

Comment: But quite possibly Dreamweaver just doesn't understand the syntax if you are using 5.4+

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Ah, i just checked and i am on 5.2.17

Comment: Not knowing that this statement isn't supported prior to php5.4 really warrants two down votes? Some people are so petty and to be honest makes me not want to come here and ask for help as such people seem to enjoy trying to make you feel small, or just stupid for not knowing something.
Thank you to those that did leave useful and constructive comments.

Comment: I kind of agree that -2 is a bit much on this, but you could possibly have avoided it if you had run the code and then posted the error message it produced instead of just mentioning that DW didn't like it. In doing so, the site would likely have suggested other questions with the same error that could have pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: Question updated with further information as the original code is obviously flawed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can possibly change this code into:

```
$qs = explode('&',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
$pid = explode('=',$qs[0]);
```

to get rid of this red mark.

But in fact Dreamweaver is not a PHP editor, you should simple choose something else to write your PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass a string to `explode()` so try with `implode()` use `limit -1` to get first array of explode

```
$pid = explode('=',implode('=',explode('&',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],-1)));
```

else you need to two statement

```
$fr = explode('&',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
$pid = explode('=',$fr[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver does'n recognise PHP 5.4, and as Michael stated, this expression is only correct since version 5.4

Comment: Ergo, Dreamweaver sucks :D